# How to send Json object with android push notification in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the following code to send push notification, and it is working fine with message as a normal string, if i inserts the message into JSON it dosen't works?

```
var GCM = require('gcm').GCM;
var gcm = new GCM('MyApi');

var message = {
    registration_id: ['x'],  
    collapse_key: 'New shop created - duty paid shop', // normal string is working
    // collapse_key: {'message':'new shop created','shopname':'shopname'}, this JSON dosen't works ?
    priority: 'high',
    contentAvailable: true,
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
};

gcm.send(message, function(err, messageId){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Sent with message ID: ", messageId);
    }
});
```

while using the JSON the error is like "Missing Collapse_Key"

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
var GCM = require('gcm').GCM;
var gcm = new GCM('MyApi');

var message = {
registration_id: ['x'],  
//collapse_key: 'New shop created - duty paid shop', // normal string is working
collapse_key: '{\'message\':\'new shop created\',\'shopname\':\'shopname\'}',
priority: 'high',
contentAvailable: true,
delayWhileIdle: true,
timeToLive: 3,
};

gcm.send(message, function(err, messageId){
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log("Sent with message ID: ", messageId);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**collapse_key can only be a string not json**

> Check Documentation here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json

You can send json in data(payload) as

```
var GCM = require('gcm').GCM;
var gcm = new GCM('MyApi');

var message = {
    registration_id: ['x'],  
    collapse_key: 'New shop created - duty paid shop',
    priority: 'high',
    notification: {title: "hello", message: "hello world"}, // for recieving notification on app side plus you need write separate notification handling function on app //A
    contentAvailable: true,
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
    data: {'message':'new shop created','shopname':'shopname'}
};

gcm.send(message, function(err, messageId){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Sent with message ID: ", messageId);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes your point is absolutely correct, but if i am sending message with data as JSON, it is empty while receiving ?

Comment: In order to recieve notification on app you need add notification key within message

Answer (score 0):

we can send json data with "node-gcm" module

```
var gcm     = require('node-gcm');
var apiKey  = 'ApiKey';

var message = new gcm.Message({
        collapseKey: 'demo',
        priority: 'normal',
        contentAvailable: true,
        delayWhileIdle: true,
        timeToLive: 3,
        data:{"message":"New Shop Created","shopName":"XYZ"}
    });

    var sender = new gcm.Sender(apiKey);

    sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: 'id'}, function (err, response) {

        if (err){
            console.error(err);
        } else  {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```